# Outlook ignoring reply-to address on auto-responder

Tags: email, outlook

We got the following situation: On our websites we got forms, which when sending use as sender a static eMail-address, so the form won't land in spam at the customer, if the eMail-address is not valid.

So now we have set the from-addres to a no-reply@example.org and the reply-to-address to the address, which the person inserted, when completing the form.

When replying in Outlook directly, it works perfectly and outlook replies to the reply-to-address. But when we enable the out-of-office auto-reply, it replies directly to the from-address, means that it completely ignores the reply-to-address.

Is there any workaround or a solution, how this can be fixed?

**EDIT:**
We are using the installed Outlook client, not the OWA. And the eMail-Address, which auto-replies is an O365 Exchange Address

Comment: i am looking for the same, comment if you find any solution

Comment: @GovindSingh sadly we didn't find any solution to this yet.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a Microsoft flow based tool that implements exactly what you want.
Google for "auto-reply ms flow".